# ajax php drop down list

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, drop-down-menu

Can some one tell me what's wrong with this example code on this site http://www.x-developer.com/php-scripts/loading-drop-downs-with-ajax-php-and-fetching-values-from-database-without-refreshing-the-page

Basically i did exactly the same as in the turorial and the problem is that the 2nd drop down list is no showing anything. I read one of the comments that someone forgot to add in some javascript on the page. How do i do this?

I have tried posting a question on that site but no one answered for a week now so I came here.

Any help would be much appreciated.

this is my index.php page

```
<?php
include('cn.php');

$sql_country = "SELECT * FROM COUNTRY";
$result_country = mysql_query($sql_country);

echo "<select name='country' onChange='get_cities(this.value)'>"; //get_cities is defined below

while($row_country = mysql_fetch_array($result_country))
{
echo "<option value='".$row_country['id']."'>".$row_country['country']."</option>";
}

echo "</select>";

echo "<select name='city' id='city'></select>"; //We have given id to this dropdown

?>
```

this is my get_cities.js page

```
function get_cities(country_id)
{
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "cities.php", /* The country id will be sent to this file */
   beforeSend: function () {
  $("#city").html("<option>Loading ...</option>");
    },
   data: "country_id="+country_id,
   success: function(msg){
     $("#city").html(msg);
   }
   });
 }
```

This is my cities.php page

```
<?php

include('cn.php');

// Code for cities.php
$country_id = $_REQUEST['country_id'];

$sql_city = "SELECT * FROM CITY WHERE country_id = '".$country_id."'";
$result_city = mysql_query($sql_city);
echo "<select name='city'>";

while($row_city = mysql_fetch_array($result_city))
{
echo "<option value='".$row_city['id']."'>".$row_city['city']."</option>";
}

echo "</select>";

?>
```

The included 'cn.php' is just my connection to the database.

Comment: Let us see what code you have so we can check what yo are doing?

Comment: can you checked the console. use firebug and check in console.

Comment: Did you make sure to put the php code in the php file, and include jquery?

Comment: The problem is that the exampled code is using mysql_* functions.

Comment: I have now edited the original question to include the scripts i made

Comment: You are using [an **obsolete** database API](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/19068) and should use a [modern replacement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).  You are also **vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/)** that a modern API would make it easier to [defend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) yourself from.

Comment: @ Quentin I am only trying to see if i could get this script working so i can somehow then have an idea of how to put things together in my project

Comment: Sorry for the newbie questions, I am only new to coding so anything you describe needs to be in detail and easy to understand.

Comment: Have you got JQuery installed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
//Index.php
<?php
$conn = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "root");
$db = mysql_select_db("country_example", $conn);

$sql_country = "SELECT * FROM country";
$result_country = mysql_query($sql_country);

?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Country List</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php 

echo "<select name='country' onChange='get_cities(this.value)'>";

while($row_country = mysql_fetch_array($result_country))
{
    echo "<option value='".$row_country['id']."'>".$row_country['country']."</option>";
}
echo "</select>";
echo "<div id='cityLayer'><select name='city' id='city'></select></div>";
?>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
    function get_cities($country_id){
     $.ajax({
         url : "city.php?country_id="+$country_id,
         cache : false,
         beforeSend : function (){
              //Show a message
         },
         complete : function($response, $status){
             if ($status != "error" && $status != "timeout") {
                 $('#cityLayer').html($response.responseText);
             }
         },
         error : function ($responseObj){
             alert("Something went wrong while processing your request.\n\nError => "
                 + $responseObj.responseText);
         }
     }); 
    }
 </script>
</body>
</html>

//City.php
<?php

$conn = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "root");
$db = mysql_select_db("country_example", $conn);

$country_id = $_REQUEST['country_id'];
$sql_city = "SELECT * FROM cities WHERE country_id = '".$country_id."'";
$result_city = mysql_query($sql_city);

echo "<select name='city'>";
while($row_city = mysql_fetch_array($result_city))
{
    echo "<option value='".$row_city['id']."'>".$row_city['city']."</option>";
}
echo "</select>";
?>
```

Comment: Not tested but should work..

Comment: @ Jay Bhatt The code you gave above shows this error "Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\wamp\www\test\index.php on line 7"  and "Notice: Undefined index: country_id in C:\wamp\www\test\index.php on line 17"

Comment: @kev that means that the value of $result_country is false. Did you add in your database connection?

Comment: Include include('cn.php'); in your script..

Comment: post the output of http://localhost/test/city.php?country_id=10

Comment: Sorry what do you mean the output of the above? Where do i put the javascript bit in?

Comment: Call the script which gets cities from database with the parameter country_id=10. If the script name is city.php then call it like city.php?country_id=10 and let me know whether it shows you data or error...

Comment: Also have you included Jquery in your script? The Ajax function used in javascript requires Jquery....Add following to your country file..<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' in C:\wamp\www\test\index.php on line 3. This error is showing when i paste the above in the countries file. Maybe i put it incorrectly? Where should i paste it in the country file?

Comment: The javascript function, is that meant to be saved in a .js file ?

Comment: It should be in the country file. See the updated answer...

Comment: ok i will try this thnx

Comment: The code contains two different files and depending on your city file change the value of this line url : "cities.php?country_id="+$country_id,

Comment: Wait...will send you the code...

Comment: http://theitbranch.com/transfer/country.zip  working code...

Comment: @ Jay Bhatt Sorry for the long response and Thnx for the help, i will try your code!